# Instagram Sharer Url

Tags: javascript, share, social-networking

I need to build a share link for instagram.

for example, 
these are the sharer url for others socials:

```js
export const SOCIALS = {
  twitter: "http://twitter.com/intent/tweet/?url=",
  facebook: "http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=",
  pinterest: "http://pinterest.com/pin/create/button/?url="
};
```

now, what's the link for instagram?

Comment: https://help.instagram.com/684926628219030

Comment: It means they have a whole API section which you should review first..

Comment: Then you should know they don't have a URL based sharing system, they seem to base their sharing through their api, which involves prepared requests. Something surrounding Instagram-Direct

Answer (score -1):

You cannot share media on Instagram using the API. Due to multiple reason and regulations set by Instagram to allow better experience of the product.